# sass list to multiple selector with ','

Tags: sass

i got a headache

i tried find a solution, but there has nothing for like this problem.

my code almost like below

```
@mixin test(){
  &:after {
    content: 'yes';
  }
}

$selectors:();
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  $selectors: append($selectors, 'h'+$i);
}

#{$selectors} {
  @include test;
}
```

i want make to result as

```
h1:after, h2:after, h3:after {
    content: 'yes';
}
```

but i got

```
h1 h2 h3:after {
    content: 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SASS**

```
%test{
  &:after {
    content: 'yes';
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  h#{$i}  { @extend %test; }
}
```

**OUTPUT CSS**

```
h1:after, h2:after, h3:after {
  content: 'yes';
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use your code, you can do like this:

```
@mixin test(){
  &:after {
    content: 'yes';
  }
}

$selectors:();
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  $selectors: append($selectors, ('h'+$i), comma);
}

#{$selectors} {
  @include test;
}
```

Comment: it's work. and more than easy. thanks for your answer. if you know, please tell me again. is it impossible like my style? i tried use join like other langauge. but it's not work.